# SyncTask in separate class, reach my views

Tags: android

I have Asynch in a separate class, and I need to change setText on some of the TextViews

How this possible? 
OR should I keep AsyncTask inside my Class?

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, AdModel> {
    @Override
    protected AdModel doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return getAd();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(AdModel result) {
        textTitle.setText(result.getTitle());

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a constructor for your AsyncTask that takes a reference to your activity. You might want to be careful about not leaking your activity reference by nulling it out from within your AsyncTask when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask {

```
private TextView text;

DownloadImageTask(TextView txtToUpdate) {
     text = txtToUpdate;
}

@Override
protected AdModel doInBackground(Object... params) {
    return getAd();

}

protected void onPostExecute(AdModel result) {
    text.setText(result.getTitle());
    text = null;
 }
```

}

or ..better... create listener interface, which You will invoke at onPostExecute. Implementation of listener interface should update TextView.